# After adding dropout, my neural network is overfitting even more than before. What's going on?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I was working on a network that counts the number of sea lions in drone images for a Kaggle competition, which just ended. The sea lions are also differentiated by class (adult male, adult female, etc). Please help me understand why adding dropout to this network did not work.

The network architecture in Keras is copied below. Initially, I took the first fifteen layers of VGG16 pretrained on Imagenet. On top of those I put seven layers: Convolutional, RELU, Pooling, Convolutional, RELU, Pooling, and global average pooling to output the counts. This model overfit the data during training, ending with a loss of 400 or 500 (excellent scores) but a holdout validation loss of ~850 (decent). Then, I added 50% dropout after the VGG layers and again after each of the layers I added. This was per the [Stanford cs231 online course notes](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#reg)  - "It is also common to combine this with dropout applied after all layers. The value of p=0.5 is a reasonable default." After training this for a while, training loss had come down to ~800 but holdout validation loss was still stuck at 1200+ (not good at all), which it had reached much earlier in the training.

Why didn't adding dropout work? Is something else such as the architecture, the task, or the optimizer somehow the issue?

Edit: Also, there are only ~800 training images and another ~150 in the holdout validation set, but I was also using data augmentation with horizontal flip, vertical flip, and up to 180 degrees of rotation.

```
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

x = base_model.layers[15].output
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Conv2D(n_classes, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
        optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adadelta())
```

Comment: Did you use data augmentation also in the validation set? (Perhaps the augmentation made the training set different enough from the validation set?)

Comment: Hmm I did not, let me try that in the next hour or so and get back to you with the result. That being said, I don't think any of those changes would lead to an image that could be distinguished from the original training set unless the rotation does something weird

Comment: Why do you add the Dropout twice for each of the `Conv2D` layers? `x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)` This will certainly cause trouble since you might randomly erase almost all neurons during training.

Comment: @Daniel Ok I tried using data augmentation on the holdout set, but the loss was even higher (1300+) so I don't think that is what caused the issue.

Comment: @petezurich Ahh ok, thanks, good point. I was thinking of those as separate layers but now I see what you're saying. What I thought of as the second of those layers is actually just applying the RELU function to the convolutional layer. Ok I removed both lines that added dropout between those two and I'm training again from scratch. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @petezurich Ok, looks like that improved the network but didn't solve the problem. Holdout loss plateaued at ~1100 while training loss has continued to decrease to ~750. In contrast, without dropout, by the time it reached ~750 training loss it had achieved ~850 holdout loss. So dropout still makes the overfitting significantly worse. That's so weird!

Comment: Can you post the training history?

Comment: @petezurich I haven't been saving the training history, but I do save frequent checkpoints of the models so I can easily regenerate any section of the history you would like to see. What are you hoping to learn from the training history?

Comment: Usually it helps to see the history to check for any anomalies or hints to what could cause this unusual behaviour. Does your model immediately start to learn? For how long do your train & val losses converge? When and why do you abort training? It´s just a habit of mine to always use Tensorboard or the history from model.fit() itself to see whats going on.

Comment: @petezurich Got it working! I noticed in the Keras summary there are no trainable parameters in the pooling layer, so I removed dropout after that layer as well. Now it's showing significantly less overfitting compared to the original network. This is just an extension of what you originally said, so if you would like to add it all as an answer I'll mark that as correct. If you have any additional insight on why pooling does not count as a separate layer, that would also be appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! And you´re welcome. I am happy that you could solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you remove the redundant Dropout that you have added for each convolutional layer:

```
x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x) # <-- redundant, remove this
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x) <-- remove this as well
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
```

In addition to that I recommend to check your training history either with the history of model.fit() or Tensorboard to check for any anomalies that might explain that unusual behaviour of your losses.